# Automatically update attribute when another attribute is updated

Tags: laravel

I have a model `Bucket` with two attributes: `name` and `slug`.

`name` can be any string, and `slug` is an url friendly version of `name`. Users can update a bucket `name`, but the `slug` should be automatically generated based off the name. Here's my controller code.

```
$bucket = Auth::user()->buckets()->find($id);
if(!$bucket) return App::abort(404,'Bucket not found');

$bucket->fill(Input::all());
$bucket->save();
return $bucket;
```

With the given code, `name` updates but `slug` does not. How do I tell `Bucket` to automatically update `slug` whenever `name` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with a model event:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events

```
Bucket::updated(function($bucket){
    $bucket->slug = $bucket->slug;
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about these. Thanks!